# Как selenium webdriver отлавливать реквесты с сайта

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, request, fiddler

может кто-то сталкивался с подобным тестированием и может помочь

Задача: Нужно отлавливать реквесты, которые уходят с сайта при выполнении любых действий (клик на ссылку, переход по линке, заполнение формы и т.д.). В параметрах этих реквестов хранится множество аналитической информации, которую нужно проверять.
Подскажите, как с помощью вебдрайвера можно получить реквесты, которые уходят с сайта? Возможно есть какие то другие утилиты? Может можно подключить фидлер, который будет ловить эти запросы? Но тесты должны оставаться параллельными

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SeleniumWebDriver для такого не предназначен. Он предназначен для тестирования Web UI в "реальных условиях" конечного пользователя.

Для того что бы тестировать реквесты тебе нужен инструментарий с настройкой локального прокси. Локальный прокси выступает посредником между запросами браузера и интернетом и может логгировать каждый из реквестов. Примеры подобного функционала можно назвать [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com) или [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)... Или тот же [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org). Но я не уверен что это именно те инструменты которые нужны тебе, ведь я не знаю как у них с коннектом к языкам программирования, в частности c#.

Но что я знаю наверняка, так это то, что тебе точно не подходит для данной задачи Selenium. И не должен подходить, даже, в теории.